# How to handle multiple destination in Baidu Map using URI in Android/IOS

Tags: android, ios, maps, baidu, baidu-map

We are integrating Baidu map and wants to show multiple stoppages (destinations) over the map. We have gone through official documentation of Baidu maps(http://lbsyun.baidu.com/index.php?title=uri/api/android) and found a parameter named 'viaPoints'. As per document, we need to pass JSON in `viaPoints` key but we are unable to append JSON in URL.

In android we are passing like this :

```
Intent i1 = new Intent();
i1.setData(Uri.parse("baidumap://map/direction?mode=driving&destination=上上&origin=西二旗&src=push&viaPoints={viaPoints:[{name:Beijing West Railway Station, lat:39.902463,lng:116.327737}]}"));
startActivity(i1);
```

We want to achieve multiple destinations as shown in attached image.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem in iOS?

Comment: Same as explained above

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation you mentioned looks to be in Chinees but got an idea.

You are not using double quotes around the array `viaPoints` and other keys in the JSON parameter.

JSON needs to be in this format

```
{
  "viaPoints": [
    {
      "name": "Beijing West Railway Station",
      "lat": 39.902463,
      "lng": 116.327737
    }]
}
```

Try this

```
i1.setData(Uri.parse("baidumap://map/direction?mode=driving&destination=上上&origin=西二旗&src=push&viaPoints={\"viaPoints\":[{\"name\":\"Beijing West Railway Station\", \"lat\":39.902463,\"lng\":116.327737}]}"));
```

Comment: `Uri.parse("baidumap://map/direction?mode=driving&destination=上上&origin=西二旗&src=push&viaPoints={"viaPoints":[{"name":"Beijing West Railway Station", "lat":39.902463,"lng":116.327737}]}")` you know that this would not even compile ... but I think you are right but wrote wrong code

Comment: @Selvin: Right, needed to escape.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Instantiates a new Polyline object and adds points to define a rectangle
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Comment: Hey, my question is regarding Baidu map not google map.